# How long does it take to update a plugin page from the readme.txt?

Tags: plugin-development

So I updated [my plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/op-archive/) this morning to a new version and made some changes to the readme.txt (basic FAQ, changelog info). But the plugin site isn't reflecting the changes.

I updated the 'Stable tag' to version 0.0.2, then copied the trunk file to the tags/0.0.2 directory. The svn page shows the correct readme.txt . Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It normally takes at most 15 minutes before the Extend page is refreshed, so just give it a little while.

Comment: been about 2 hours, and the page is showing the correct new version.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure both the 'stable version' is updated in the readme.txt AND the 'version' number is updated in the header of your-plugin.php, in addition to adding a new tag.

I've seen it take over 15 minutes but usually updated within the hour. If I get real desperate I'll do a minor readme change, double check all my version numbers, cp trunk/* to tags/0.x.x and do an additional commit.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 28th, 2011 [the repo now updates in near real-time](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/the-plugins-directory-should-now-update-in-near-real-time/).